# Unity3d ERROR: `System.Console' does not contain a definition for `CursorLeft'

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

am programming a dedicated server inside unity3d and i will run it in -batchmode and -nographics. So if i made an Console.Print(); it's doesn't anything. I started to programming something permetting to write in the console and read lines form the console. When i got started i had a lot of problems. A lot of methods/ properties aren't not recognized from System.Console but not only from Console. I need some help with this. I have read somewhere than i must removing the core called dxncore50 in a project.json but i don't have any fille called like that. But i don't have any idea if it is true and how to do it.

Here's an example of code returning me the similar error with the title.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Windows
{
    public class ConsoleInput
    {
        public void Awake()
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = 0; //THE ERROR'S HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link: http://garry.tv/2014/04/23/unity-batchmode-console/

Comment: @mayo I tried before asking this question here, i had the same problems... same errors... than now

Comment: mm, what about this comment (almost the last comment on the site):
"Anyone else trying to implement this in their unity project, you have to change the .net version of unity in the player settings in Unity 5 from .net 2.0 subset to .net 2.0 or it will give about 19 console errors. Once you do that you will be left with one error in ServerConsole.cs on line 38, you can either comment it out until you create your in game console and then send the string to that or you can directly send the string if you already have a console system. "

Comment: @mayo Thank you very mutch for your help.

Comment: It works? Are you Ok if I make an answer of this question?

Comment: read tags, it's not `unity`. use `unity3d`

Comment: @mayo All works very well but when i'am writing in the console to console write 2 times the char exemple if i write "Server" the console will write "SSeerrvveerr"

Comment: @Azerty, I will add a answer :) . And I think that you can make another new question for the new problem :)

Answer (score 1):

According almost the last comment on this link:

http://garry.tv/2014/04/23/unity-batchmode-console/

> Anyone else trying to implement this in their unity project, you have
>   to change the .net version of unity in the player settings in Unity 5
>   from .net 2.0 subset to .net 2.0 or it will give about 19 console
>   errors. Once you do that you will be left with one error in
>   ServerConsole.cs on line 38, you can either comment it out until you
>   create your in game console and then send the string to that or you
>   can directly send the string if you already have a console system.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is happening because you are working in the Windows namespace. Also you should check that you are referencing the mscorlib assembly. Finally, the asp.net tag is for websites. I do not think you are using that here.

Comment: removing the namespace don't change any think i tried.

Comment: You should include a namespace, but not Windows. Also check your references for the mscorlib assembly. Should be found as System

Comment: I changed to namespace but i have the same error, i have chacked to mscorlib System. and all it's ok but i have the same error.